# Cytoscape edgehandles ghost preview shows "undefined" when dragging from one node to another

Tags: cytoscape.js

When using edgehandles, the cytoscape extension, to create an edge between two nodes [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1g6q.png), I see "undefined" at the edge of the arrow. Is there some attribute I can set to get rid of this? Either in the inputs or in the style page with a selector?

For reference, I'm using
`var eh = cy.edgehandles({defaults})` and `eh.enableDrawMode()` with the defaults defined in the [edgehandles github](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-edgehandles).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), without some code we can only guess whats wrong.

One guess would be the `cy.edgehandles({defaults})`, I think you need `cy.edgehandles(defaults)` without the parentheses? Also, the defaults are automatically applied to the edgehandles if you just call `cy.edgehandles()` as far as I know, you only need to add options if you want to modify them.

Answer (score 2):

The code from the edge-handles demo works fine in my snippet, you can use that as a starting point:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),

    layout: {
      name: 'grid',
      rows: 2,
      cols: 2
    },

    style: [{
        selector: 'node[name]',
        style: {
          'content': 'data(name)'
        }
      },

      {
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
          'curve-style': 'bezier',
          'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
        }
      },

      {
        selector: '.eh-handle',
        style: {
          'background-color': 'red',
          'width': 12,
          'height': 12,
          'shape': 'ellipse',
          'overlay-opacity': 0,
          'border-width': 12, // makes the handle easier to hit
          'border-opacity': 0
        }
      },

      {
        selector: '.eh-hover',
        style: {
          'background-color': 'red'
        }
      },

      {
        selector: '.eh-source',
        style: {
          'border-width': 2,
          'border-color': 'red'
        }
      },

      {
        selector: '.eh-target',
        style: {
          'border-width': 2,
          'border-color': 'red'
        }
      },

      {
        selector: '.eh-preview, .eh-ghost-edge',
        style: {
          'background-color': 'red',
          'line-color': 'red',
          'target-arrow-color': 'red',
          'source-arrow-color': 'red'
        }
      },

      {
        selector: '.eh-ghost-edge.eh-preview-active',
        style: {
          'opacity': 0
        }
      }
    ],

    elements: {
      nodes: [{
          data: {
            id: 'j',
            name: 'Jerry'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'e',
            name: 'Elaine'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'k',
            name: 'Kramer'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'g',
            name: 'George'
          }
        }
      ],
      edges: [{
          data: {
            source: 'j',
            target: 'e'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'j',
            target: 'k'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'j',
            target: 'g'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'e',
            target: 'j'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'e',
            target: 'k'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'k',
            target: 'j'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'k',
            target: 'e'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'k',
            target: 'g'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'g',
            target: 'j'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  });

  var eh = cy.edgehandles();

  document.querySelector('#draw-on').addEventListener('click', function() {
    eh.enableDrawMode();
  });

  document.querySelector('#draw-off').addEventListener('click', function() {
    eh.disableDrawMode();
  });

  document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', function() {
    eh.start(cy.$('node:selected'));
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#buttons {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>cytoscape-edgehandles.js demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-edgehandles@3.6.0/cytoscape-edgehandles.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>cytoscape-edgehandles demo</h1>

  <div id="cy"></div>

  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="start">Start on selected</button>
    <button id="draw-on">Draw mode on</button>
    <button id="draw-off">Draw mode off</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the problem, realized I had some code for the node-html-label extension that was interfering with how the edgehandles were being made.